# calling jquery function with one id for many instead of individual id

Tags: jquery, html

Sorry if my title sounded crazy I wasn't exactly sure how to look it up.

I have a jquery function that's called with a mouse hover. I can do it fine if every html tag has a unique id. It just seems like a total waste of repetitiveness

The jquery I'm calling with the mouse over

```
$('#ex1').zoom();
$('#ex2').zoom();
$('#ex3').zoom();
$('#ex4').zoom();
$('#ex5').zoom(); 
$('#ex6').zoom();
$('#ex7').zoom();
$('#ex8').zoom();
$('#ex9').zoom();
```

my HTML

```
<ul id="grid">   
  <li><div class="title">1</div><a href="#" class="zoom" id="ex1"><img src="1.jpg"><span></span></a></li>
  <li><div class="title">2</div><a href="#" class="zoom" id="ex2" ><img src="2.jpg"><span></span></a></li>
  <li><div class="title">3</div><a href="#" class="zoom" id="ex3"><img src="3.jpg"><span></span></a></li>
  <li><div class="title">4</div><a href="#" class="zoom" id="ex4"><img src="4.jpg"><span></span></a></li>
  <li><div class="title">5</div><a href="#" class="zoom" id="ex5"><img src="5.jpg"><span></span></a></li>
  <li><div class="title">6</div><a href="#" class="zoom" id="ex6"><img src="6.jpg"><span></span></a></li>
  <li><div class="title">7</div><a href="#" class="zoom" id="ex7"><img src="7.jpg"><span></span></a></li>
  <li><div class="title">8</div><a href="#" class="zoom" id="ex8"><img src="8.jpg"><span></span></a></li>
  <li><div class="title">9</div><a href="#" class="zoom" id="ex9"><img src="9.jpg"> <span></span></a></li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a class, use it!

```
$(".zoom").zoom();
```

Answer (score 1):

In case `.zoom` is used somewhere else, you may use

`$("[id^=ex]")` which will select all elements which ID starts with **ex** or you can use class but more specific:

`$("#grid li a.zoom")` which will select only **a** elements in **ul#grid** that has **zoom** class.